Unable to Upload File to Crowdin Storage: Request Failed with Status Code 400
I'm encountering an issue while trying to upload a file to Crowdin Storage using Node.js. Here's the problem:
Description: When attempting to upload a file to Crowdin Storage, I'm getting an error response with status code 400.
Error Message:
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "error": {
        "key": "fileStream",
        "errors": [
          {
            "code": "streamIsEmpty",
            "message": "Stream size is null. Not empty content expected"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

Approach:
I'm using Axios for making HTTP requests.
I've verified that the file exists and is not empty before uploading.
I've set the necessary headers (Authorization, Crowdin-API-FileName, Content-Type) as required by the Crowdin API documentation.
I'm appending the file to FormData with the correct key.
Code Snippet:
const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Replace with your actual Crowdin API key and project ID
const CROWDIN_API_KEY = 'crowdin_api_key';
const CROWDIN_PROJECT_ID = 123467890;

// Function to upload file to Crowdin storage
const uploadFileToStorage = async (filePath) => {
    try {
        const fileName = path.basename(filePath);

        // Check if file exists and is not empty
        if (!fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
            throw new Error(`File does not exist: ${filePath}`);
        }
        const stats = fs.statSync(filePath);
        if (stats.size === 0) {
            throw new Error(`File is empty: ${filePath}`);
        }

        const form = new FormData();
        const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

        form.append('file', fileStream);

        console.log('Uploading file to Crowdin:', fileName);
        const response = await axios.post('https://api.crowdin.com/api/v2/storages', form, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${CROWDIN_API_KEY}`,
                'Crowdin-API-FileName': fileName,
                ...form.getHeaders()
            }
        });

        return response.data.data.id;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error uploading file to storage:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
        if (error.response) {
            console.error('Response status:', error.response.status);
            console.error('Response data:', JSON.stringify(error.response.data, null, 2));
        }
        throw error;
    }
};

// Function to add file to Crowdin project
const addFileToProject = async (storageId, fileName) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(`https://api.crowdin.com/api/v2/projects/${CROWDIN_PROJECT_ID}/files`, {
            storageId: storageId,
            name: fileName
        }, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${CROWDIN_API_KEY}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });

        console.log('File added to project successfully:', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error adding file to project:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
        if (error.response) {
            console.error('Response status:', error.response.status);
            console.error('Response data:', JSON.stringify(error.response.data, null, 2));
        }
        throw error;
    }
};

// Main function to upload file to Crowdin
const uploadFileToCrowdin = async (filePath) => {
    try {
        const storageId = await uploadFileToStorage(filePath);
        const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
        await addFileToProject(storageId, fileName);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error processing the file:', error.message);
    }
};

// Get the file path from command line arguments and call the upload function
const filePath = process.argv[2];
if (!filePath) {
    console.error('Please provide the file path as an argument.');
    process.exit(1);
}

uploadFileToCrowdin(filePath);


Additional Info:
I'm able to successfully authenticate with the Crowdin API using the provided API key.
I've tested the Crowdin API endpoints using Postman, and they seem to work fine.
I'm unsure why I'm encountering this error. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Crowdin provides the official JS API client. I would highly recommend using this client to avoid having to do everything "manually". The API client already encapsulates everything related to reading the file, building the request, and parsing the response. It also provides some additional helper functions.
For example:
const crowdin = require('@crowdin/crowdin-api-client');

// initialization of crowdin client
const {
  uploadStorageApi,
  sourceFilesApi
} = new crowdin.default({
  token: 'personalAccessToken',
  organization: 'organizationName' // optional
});

async function createFile() {
  const projectId = 123;
  const fileData = "content"; // your file content

  const storage = await uploadStorageApi.addStorage('file1.json', fileData);
  const file = await sourceFilesApi.createFile(projectId, {
    name: 'file1.json',
    title: 'Sample file',
    storageId: storage.data.id,
    type: 'json'
  });
  console.log(file);
}

References:

More examples

